# Restart dead accumulo tablet server

Tags: accumulo

I use a single-instance Accumulo database. It worked all fine until I tried to ingest multiple data (following [this](http://www.geomesa.org/geomesa-gdelt-analysis/) tutorial), then my tablet sever died.

I tried to restart it (using `bin/start-all` or `bin/start-here`) but it did not work. Then I restarted the whole server and it seams, that `bin/start-all` starts the tablet server first:

```
WARN : Using Zookeeper /root/Installs/zookeeper-3.4.6/zookeeper-3.4.6.  Use version 3.3.0 or greater to avoid zookeeper deadlock bug.
Starting monitor on localhost
WARN : Max open files on localhost is 1024, recommend 32768
Starting tablet servers .... done
Starting tablet server on 46.101.229.80
WARN : Max open files on 46.101.229.80 is 1024, recommend 32768
OpenJDK Client VM warning: You have loaded library /root/Installs/hadoop-2.6.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
2016-01-27 04:44:18,778 [util.NativeCodeLoader] WARN : Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2016-01-27 04:44:23,770 [fs.VolumeManagerImpl] WARN : dfs.datanode.synconclose set to false in hdfs-site.xml: data loss is possible on hard system reset or power loss
2016-01-27 04:44:23,803 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Attempting to talk to zookeeper
2016-01-27 04:44:24,246 [server.Accumulo] INFO : ZooKeeper connected and initialized, attempting to talk to HDFS
2016-01-27 04:44:24,802 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Connected to HDFS
Starting master on 46.101.229.80
WARN : Max open files on 46.101.229.80 is 1024, recommend 32768
Starting garbage collector on 46.101.229.80
WARN : Max open files on 46.101.229.80 is 1024, recommend 32768
Starting tracer on 46.101.229.80
WARN : Max open files on 46.101.229.80 is 1024, recommend 32768
```

But checking the monitor the tablet server is still dead.

The `tserver_46.101.229.80.err`-log ist empty, the `tserver_46.101.229.80.out`-log says:

```
OpenJDK Client VM warning: You have loaded library /root/Installs/hadoop-2.6.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 3225"...
```

How can I get the tabletServer up again?

I use a 32-bit 14.04 Linux of DigitalOcean, Hadoop 2.6, ZooKeeper 3.4.6 and Accuulo 1.6.4

Answer (score 0):

If the TabletServer is repeatedly crashing with an OutOfMemoryError, you need to increase the JVM maximum heap size via the -Xmx option in the ACCUMULO_TSERVER_OPTS in accumulo-env.sh.

Comment: Thanks, will try it later. But is it actually an error? I was confused by the #, looks as if it should be commented out.

Comment: Yep, it's actually an error.  Here the # is just trying to draw your attention to the message, rather than indicating a comment.